# How can I calculate the probability of a condition concerning ranked values from the same distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

How can I calculate in Mathematica the probability of a condition concerning ranked values from the same distribution?

For instance: Pr[x1 - x2 < 1 | {x1, x2} ~ N(0,1)], where x1 is the second ranked (highest value) and x2 the first ranked (lowest value) both drawn from a standard normal distribution.

I'm actually looking at a much more complicated condition* than this, but a general solution applied to the example above should already help me!

*Pr[x1 - x2 > (2 a y + 3 (x2 - L))/(4 a b - 3) | {x1, x2} ~ N(L,var_x), y ~ N(0,var_y)], where x1 is the second ranked and x2 the first ranked drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: Have you already seen `OrderDistribution[]`?

Comment: I didn't! Thanks. I now tried this, but it keeps giving a probability equal to 1. Any idea what's going wrong?
Probability[
 x1 - x2 < 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] 
  OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, 1], 2}, {1, 2}]]

-- (Flipping the k^th order statistic such that x2 is the first ranked (lowest value) and x1 is the second ranked (highest value) does not seem to solve the problem.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `x2 - x1 < 1`, considering the ranking of the result of `OrderDistribution[]`? It is possible that *Mathematica* does not know a closed form for the underlying integral; you will then need to use `NProbability[]` instead.

Comment: You're right on the ranking. It should read 'Probability[
 x1 - x2 < 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] 
  OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, 1], 2}, {2, 1}]]'. Unfortunately this also does not work (gives 0). Problem remains with NProbability (once specifying an accuracy goal).

Comment: What does `NProbability[x2 - x1 < 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[], 2}, {1, 2}]]` return for you?

Comment: The answer! (0.5205)

NProbability[
 x1 - x2 < 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] 
  OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, 1], 2}, {2, 1}]] does not work, but NProbability[
 x2 - x1 < 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] 
  OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, 1], 2}, {1, 2}]] does, where x2 is now the highest value and x1 the lowest. Many thanks!!

Comment: I think your more complicated condition can be simplified without loss of generality by setting $L=0$ as the left-hand side of the equation can be written as $(x1-L)-(x2-L)$.

Answer (score 5):

One can take this example further by working outside of the limitations of black boxes, by working with the actual input and outputs involved.

**Short version:**  The exact answer is:  `Erf[1/2]`

**Longer version:**
Given parent random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/helloMrNormalpdf4.png))</sub>

Then, given a sample of size 2 drawn on parent $X$, the joint pdf of the $1^\text{st}$ and $2^\text{nd}$ order statistics is say $g(x_1,x_2)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/g12OrderStatNormal.png))</sub>

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* here which is the most familiar to me as one of the authors, or one can use *Mathematica*'s in-built `OrderDistribution` function together with `PDF`. Either way, viewing output and functional forms is crucial.

*Mathematica*'s in-built `Probability` function returns Mathematica's `Probability` function (the same user input), so I will use *mathStatica*'s `Prob` function here. In particular, we seek $P(X_2 - X_1 <1)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/CDFg12OrderStatNormal2.png))</sub>

*Mathematica* does not return a closed form solution, but by being able to see the output, we can take matters further. The `Erf[x]` term integrates out to 0, leaving an expression equivalent to:

$$E\big[ \text{Erf}\big[\frac{1+X}{\sqrt{2}}\big] \big] \; = \; E\big[ 2 F(1+X) \big] - 1$$

where $F$ denotes the cdf of a standard Normal (and where the expectation operator is with reference to parent pdf $f(x)$). The problem has now reduced to finding the expectation of the cdf of a standard Normal. *Mathematica* seems to have trouble with this too, but the expectation does have a closed form ... see, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449875/expected-value-of-normal-cdf ... from which it follows that the closed-form solution is:

$$2 F\big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big) - 1  \quad = \quad \text{Erf}[\frac12]$$

which is approximately 0.5205.